# R - aggregating data into a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I was recently working with some output and I can't seem to plot it informatively. The output looks like the following:

```
180,A,71
180,C,61
180,G,68
180,U,78
182,A,70
182,C,34
182,G,123
182,U,51
```

I would like to plot this data so i have on the x axis the first column, and on the y axis bars which are filled according to four different types(column 2) and their frequencies (column 3). So on y axis would be frequency of all types on one value from first column, but that bar would be divided according to size of types.

I hope the question was clear and thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? What did you already try yourself?

Comment: I've tried aggregate(y~x,data=data), and I don't know how to create a plot with bars composed of fractions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stacked bar plot in r with summarized data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630069/stacked-bar-plot-in-r-with-summarized-data). Your data is already in the right format though.

Comment: Is it really? Thank you I will try this method and I shall report If it works.

Comment: (Assuming the column names are V1, V2 and V3, you could try `library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=V1,y=V3,group=V2,fill=V2))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
df <- data.frame(X=rep(c(180,182), each=4), Group=rep(c("A","C","G","U"),2),
             Y=c(71,61,68,78,70,34,123,51))

# Calculating percentages (just using base)
groupSum <- tapply(df$X, df$Group, sum)
df$Label <- paste0(round(100 * df$Y / groupSum[df$Group], 1), "%")

# Go for the plot
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=X, y=Y,fill=Group)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(df$X))
```

The last part only labels the x values actually used.
[image]

And this is what @Haroka's plot would look like (with percentages now added as per request -- also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)):

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=X, y=Y,fill=Group)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(df$X)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Label), size=12, hjust=0.5, vjust=3, position="stack")
```

[image]

Comment: Simultaneous answering with @Heroka

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and it works, one more thing: how do I put on x only the values in the data and not the values inbetween?

Comment: I use scale functions for this: ` + scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(df$X))` The unique isn't strictly necessary but more expandable. Will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I've managed to obtain the first plot before, but you explained it perfectly.

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to plot percentage fractions within different colours? Sorry for late reply, It just hit me I would greatly benefit from that.

Comment: Sure. For that you need another geom. This time text. I've updated the answer again.